# Multivariate time series for multiple objects

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataset containing a few variables like this:

```
+-----+------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+--+
| id  | year | week_n | price_avg | traffic | quantity |  |
+-----+------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+--+
| 123 | 2012 |      1 |      60.0 |     800 |      400 |  |
| 123 | 2012 |      2 |      68.0 |    1000 |      560 |  |
| 123 | 2012 |      3 |      54.0 |     760 |      390 |  |
| 456 | 2014 |      4 |      44.0 |     750 |      370 |  |
| 456 | 2014 |      5 |      48.0 |     820 |      404 |  |
| 456 | 2014 |      6 |      54.0 |     800 |      410 |  |
+-----+------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+--+
```

Representing different locations with the number of products sold for each location in a given week of the year, along with some other predictors.

I need to apply a multivariate model able to predict the variable quantity for `n` future weeks. I was thinking about applying some `ARMA` models, or `ARIMA`, as the series is stationary with a Dickey-Fuller p-value of 0.15.
As in the exercise, it is asked to me to first compute a multivariate regression model, and then predict the variable quantity for the next 10 weeks.

I am a bit confused and I don't know exactly which would be a good approach in R to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As for the first part (compute multivariate regression model), you could probably start like this:

```
# making the dataframe
sannadf <- structure(list(
  ids = c(123, 123, 123, 456, 456,456), 
  year = c(2012,2012,2012,2014,2014,2014), 
  week_n = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
  price_avg =   c(60,68,54,44,48,54), 
  traffic =c(800,1000,760,750,820,800),
  quantity = c(400,560,390,370,404,410)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
  class = c("data.frame"))
sannadf$ids <- as.factor(sannadf$ids) 

# making the regression model
model <- lm(quantity ~ ids + year + week_n + price_avg + traffic, data = sannadf)
summary(model)

# making the prediction
prediction <-  predict(model)
```